# Rust GUI - Druid - Lens on complex state / ambiguous associated type

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a Widget Lens on a piece of state which is more than one level deep. Here's a simplified example:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Data, Lens)]
struct State {
    user: User
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Data, Lens)]
struct User {
    name: String
}
```

All of the examples of lenses show using a lens where there is a single state without any nested objects. Such as:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Data, Lens)]
struct MyComplexState {
    #[lens(name = "term_lens")]
    term: String,
    scale: f64,
}
fn some_gui_builder() {
    ...
    let searchbar = TextBox::new().lens(MyState::term_lens);
    ...
}
```

I tried doing this with nested state, such as:

```
    let some_input = TextBox::new().lens(State::user::name);
```

... but it doesn't seem to work. I get an ambiguous type error

```
ambiguous associated type
help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<state::State as Trait>::user`rustc(E0223)
```

I'm at a loss here. I assume since both Player and State implement lens, it is ambiguous? But if I implement it such as <state::State as Lens>::user or <state::State as Widget>::user it errors that it can't find `user` on `Widget`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the lenses using [`.then`](https://docs.rs/druid/0.6.0/druid/lens/struct.Then.html)

`let some_input = TextBox::new().lens(State::user.then(User::name));`